# Pin an app to the right side of the Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I would like to pin an app to the **RIGHT** side of the Windows 7 taskbar but I cannot figure out a way to do this. Any help in figuring out how to do this would be very welcome.

**NOT** in the System Tray.

Comment: My Grievous mistake-I ment the RIGHT side of the taskbar!

Comment: @trlkly I do NOT want the App in the sys. tray.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to to that. what's wrong with pinning to the left side of taskbar?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to do a proper pinned app (and I've not found any tools that would fix that), but you could enable the "Quick Launch" toolbar and move it over there. Unfortunately, it will still show a button on the left side when you launch it.

Comment: @trlkly I do not believe it is possible to enable the Quick Launch Bar in Win7.

Comment: It's possible. You just have to do it manually through the "New Toolbar" command. The canonical location is `%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch`, but you can use any folder you want.